# Untuple a Clojure sequence

Tags: clojure, rdd, flambo

I have a function that is deduplicating with preference, I thought of implementing the solution in clojure using flambo function thus:

1. From the data set, using the `group-by`, to group duplicates (i.e based on a specified `:key`)
2. Given a `:val` as input, using a `filter` to check if the some of values for each row are equal to this `:val`
3. Use a map to `untuple` the duplicates to return single vectors (Not very sure if that is the right way though, I tried using a `flat-map` without any luck)

For a sample data-set

```
(def rdd
   (f/parallelize sc [ ["Coke" "16" ""] ["Pepsi" "" "5"] ["Coke" "2" "3"] ["Coke" "" "36"] ["Pepsi" "" "34"] ["Pepsi" "25" "34"]]))
```

I tried this:

```
(defn dedup-rows
 [rows input]
 (let [{:keys [key-col col val]} input  
      result (-> rows
               (f/group-by (f/fn [row]
                            (get row key-col)))
              (f/values)
              (f/map (f/fn [rows]
                (if (= (count rows) 1)
                  rows
                  (filter (fn [row]
                            (let [col-val (get row col)
                                  equal? (= col-val val)]
                              (if (not equal?)
                               true
                               false))) rows)))))]
    result))
```

if I run this function thus:

```
(dedup-rows rdd {:key-col 0 :col 1 :val ""})
```

it produces

```
;=> [(["Pepsi" 25 34]), (["Coke" 16 ] ["Coke" 2 3])]]
```

I don't know what else to do to handle the result to produce a result of

```
;=> [["Pepsi" 25 34],["Coke" 16 ],["Coke" 2 3]]
```

I tried `f/map f/untuple` as the last form in the `->` macro with no luck.

Any suggestions? I will really appreciate if there's another way to go about this.
Thanks.

PS: when grouped

```
;=> [[["Pepsi" "" 5], ["Pepsi" "" 34], ["Pepsi" 25 34]], [["Coke" 16 ""], ["Coke" 2 3], ["Coke" "" 36]]]
```

For each group, rows that have`""` are considered duplicates and hence removed from the group.

Comment: @zero323, Kindly help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [flambo readme](https://github.com/yieldbot/flambo), there is a `flat-map` function. This is slightly unfortunate naming because the Clojure equivalent is called `mapcat`. These functions take each map result - which must be a sequence - and concatenates them together. Another way to think about it is that it flattens the final sequence by one level.

I can't test this but I think you should replace your `f/map` with `f/flat-map`.

Answer (score 1):

Going by @TheQuickBrownFox suggestion, I tried the following

```
(defn dedup-rows
[rows input]
(let [{:keys [key-col col val]} input  
  result (-> rows
           (f/group-by (f/fn [row]
                        (get row key-col)))
          (f/values)
          (f/map (f/fn [rows]
            (if (= (count rows) 1)
              rows
              (filter (fn [row]
                        (let [col-val (get row col)
                              equal? (= col-val val)]
                          (if (not equal?)
                           true
                           false))) rows)))
           (f/flat-map (f/fn [row]
                           (mapcat vector row)))))]
  result))
```

and seems to work